# Chart Data Based On Cell Value

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

[Project Task Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcxxT.jpg)

Hi, I'm trying to chart the progress of project tasks dependent on the status of the project. I have a table with all projects and the % progress and % remaining for all tasks associated with that project. As this table will also contain "Completed" projects as well as "Cancelled" projects I'm only wanting to chart those that have "Tentative" in one chart and "Confirmed" in another chart. Am I able to set a dynamic chart range dependant on what the value is in column C, so the charts update as a project moves from tentative, confirmed, complete etc.
I have attached a picture for reference.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I guessed at Excel based on your other question.  If you are doing this in another application, just correct the tag.

Comment: Your problem can be solved, by first Sort data on `Status column` then create `Named Range` to create `dynamic Chart Range`  to draw the required Chart,, in Excel you may use 3D Staked bar or 3D 100% Staked bar.